# How to insert data in nestjs using typeorm

Tags: graphql, nestjs, typeorm, one-to-many, many-to-one

transaction.entity.ts

```
@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class Transaction {
  @Field()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;
  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.transactions)
  user: User;
  @ManyToOne(() => Book, (book) => book.transactions)
  book: Book;
}
```

user.entity.ts

```
@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class User {
  @Field()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;
  @OneToMany(() => Transaction, (trans) => trans.user, {
    cascade: ['insert', 'update'],
  })
  public transactions: Transaction[];
}
```

book.entity.ts

```
@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class Book {
  @Field()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;
  @Field()
  @OneToMany(() => Transaction, (transaction) => transaction.book, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  transactions: Transaction[];
}
```

transactio.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class BookService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Book) private books: Repository<Book>) {}
  async create(createBookInput: CreateBookInput) {
    const newBook = await this.books.create({
      ...createBookInput,
    });
    return await this.books.save(newBook);
  }
}
```

how do you make a purchase transaction feature in nestjs using typeorm?
I want to create a transaction table with relation to the user and book tables, and how do I create a transaction feature?